# Extract common values from a key and make a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, json

I have an `array` of objects like this:

```
[
{"k1":"v1","k2":27172},
{"k1":"v1","k2":15177},
{"k1":"v1","k2":19411},
{"k1":"v2","k2":30163},
{"k1":"v2","k2":23949},
{"k1":"v2","k2":23829},
{"k1":"v2","k2":27821}
]
```

What's the easiest way to extract the common values from k1 and create a multidimensional array like the below?

```
[
["v1", [27172, 15177, 19411]],
["v2", [30163, 23949, 23829, 27821]]
];
```

Comment: Assuming this is just a mistake in the question, but it would seem that `{"k1", "v1"}` should be `{"k1": "v1"}`. If so, please edit your question to correct the syntax.

Comment: Sorry about that! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: closer needs to be `]`, not `}` in first code block

Comment: could you please elaborate on the use case?  I mean relationship between the keys and values

Comment: @ BryanGrezeszak The array of objects was provided by the software writer as is. Just had to reshape it to visualize it.

Comment: @NidhinDavid The key is the dropdown value (city, country). Depending on which dropdown is selected, different cities/cories are automatically generated and added to the k1 values. This is the data format I hope to achieve eventually. https://github.com/dataarts/webgl-globe

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service.  What have you tried?

Comment: While I disagree with your vote, I probably should have posted my few hours of trials and errors here. Stuck right here - https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=s18xzSpMq7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `reduce` function of array

```
var test = [
    { "k1": "v1", "k2": 27172 },
    { "k1": "v1", "k2": 15177 },
    { "k1": "v1", "k2": 19411 },
    { "k1": "v2", "k2": 30163 },
    { "k1": "v2", "k2": 23949 },
    { "k1": "v2", "k2": 23829 },
    { "k1": "v2", "k2": 27821 }
]

var out = test.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    res[obj.k1] = res[obj.k1] || [];
    res[obj.k1].push(obj.k2)
    return res;
}, {});

var result = [];
for (var key in out) {
    result.push([key, out[key]])
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

will give

```
[
 ["v1", [27172, 15177, 19411]],
 ["v2", [30163, 23949, 23829, 27821]]
];
```

Comment: Besides the extra **")"** at the end of **for(var key in out){
 result.push([key,out[key]]);
};**, this method is amazing. Thank you for posting!

Comment: Thanks @PeterLeger

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with some loops.

I created a jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/cucixi/edit?html,js,console

```
var list = [
            {"k1":"v1","k2":27172},
            {"k1":"v1","k2":15177},
            {"k1":"v1","k2":19411},
            {"k1":"v2","k2":30163},
            {"k1":"v2","k2":23949},
            {"k1":"v2","k2":23829},
            {"k1":"v2","k2":27821}
         ];
var data = {};
list.forEach(function(item){
  if (item.k1 in data){
     data[item.k1].push(item.k2);
  } else {
     data[item.k1] = [item.k2];
  }
});

var output = [];
for (var key in data){
  output.push([key, data[key]]);
}

console.log(output);
```

Output:

```
[
   ["v1", [27172, 27172, 15177, 15177, 19411, 19411]], 
   ["v2", [30163, 30163, 23949, 23949, 23829, 23829, 27821, 27821]]
]
```

Comment: Output was supposed to be a 2D array with 1st value being the "k1" or "k2", so another loop needed to transform to that structure.

Comment: I added  some changes in code after your question update.

Comment: Unfortunately if you look at the expected output of the update it completely changes the question asked.

Comment: I hope, now it is as you want @BryanGrezeszak

Comment: ...well, not as I want it, I'm not the OP. But look at the requirement in the OP, your result data doesn't fit the required result data. They basically changed the question on you, sorry to say.

Comment: oh, I got it.. I am really unfortunate :P

Comment: @BryanGrezeszak. I fixed it but I am very angry, why are people in so hurry that they post a wrong question and then update it 20 times. :(

Comment: My apologies. Thanks so much for the help. I've been coding on this all day. Posted before dinner. Next time I will post after dinner. :-)

Answer (score 2):

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aLnc9oh1/

The solution:

```
function solution(A)
{
    // make an object with an array of values
    var temp = {};
    for (var i=0, ii=A.length; i<ii; i++)
    {
        var prop = A[i]['k1'];
        if (temp[prop])
            temp[prop].push(A[i]['k2']);
        else
            temp[prop] = [A[i]['k2']];
    }

    // reformat that into the 2D array like desired
    var retArr = [];
    for (var key in temp)
        retArr.push([key, temp[key]]);

    // return it!
    return retArr;
}
```

For the given data returns:

```
[
    ["v1", [27172, 15177, 19411]],
    ["v2", [30163, 23949, 23829, 27821]]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a combination of `Array.prototype.map()` and `Object.keys()`

```
var obj = data.reduce((acc, x) => {
  acc[x.k1] = (acc[x.k1] || []).concat(x.k2));
  return acc;
}, {});

var res = Object.keys(obj).map(x => [x, obj[x]]);
```